# looping through json decoded array

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

This is my code to get product details from database..

```
$i=0;
        foreach($res->result() as $row ){



            $products=json_decode($row->product_name,1);
            //var_dump($products);
            /*$sess_products[$i]['product_id'] = $row->product_id;
            $sess_products[$i]['product_name'] = $row->product_name;
            $sess_products[$i]['quantity'] = $row->quantity;
            $sess_products[$i]['unit'] = $row->unit;
            $sess_products[$i]['unit_rate'] = $row->unit_rate;

            $this->session->set_userdata('sess_products',$sess_products);*/
            //$post_array['cart']=$this->session->userdata('sess_products');
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input type='hidden'  style='width:80%;'  value='".$products[$i]['product_id']."' name='product_id[]'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='hidden'  style='width:80%;'  value='".$products[$i]['product_name']."' name='product_name[]'/></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='width:40%;'>".$products[$i]['product_name']."</td>";

            echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$products[$i]['quantity']."' name='quantity[]'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$products[$i]['unit']."' name='unit[]'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$products[$i]['unit_rate']."' name='unit_rate[]'/></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' rownum='".$i."' class='remove_from_update_cart'><img src='images/close.png'/></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;

        }
```

Now I am able to display first item in json string by decoding it. but I want to display whole records in foreach loop.? So what will be the error??

**Above code display only first record from that array.**

Comment: Why you doing `$products=json_decode($product);` inside the `foreach` loop? Did you try it outside the loop?

Comment: if you want array, why dont use `$res->result_array();` [Documentation here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: Does `$row` represent a JSON or `$row->product_name`? `$row->product_name` looks more like a string column of name, not the whole product details.

Comment: give us the EXACT var_dump of `$product`.

Comment: The issue seems to be with code ignitor, which version are you using?

Comment: I'd like to say that according to the PHP manual, `json_decode()` doesn't return string; upon error, it returns `null`. This problem you're having is pretty weird.

Comment: It might sound weird but can you try decoding twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code..

```
$i=0;

        foreach($res->result() as $row ){


            $j=0;
            $products=json_decode($row->product_name,1);
            foreach($products as $row2){


            $sess_products[$j]['product_id'] = $row2['product_id'];
            $sess_products[$j]['product_name'] = $row2['product_name'];
            $sess_products[$j]['quantity'] = $row2['quantity'];
            $sess_products[$j]['unit'] = $row2['unit'];
            $sess_products[$j]['unit_rate'] = $row2['unit_rate'];

            $this->session->set_userdata('sess_products',$sess_products);
            //print_r($sess_products);
            //$post_array['cart']=$this->session->userdata('sess_products');
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input type='hidden'  style='width:80%;'  value='".$row2['product_id']."' name='product_id[]'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='hidden'  style='width:80%;'  value='".$row2['product_name']."' name='product_name[]'/></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='width:40%;'>".$row2['product_name']."</td>";


            echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$row2['quantity']."' name='quantity[]'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$row2['unit']."' name='unit[]'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$row2['unit_rate']."' name='unit_rate[]'/></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' rownum='".$j."' class='remove_from_update_cart'><img src='images/close.png'/></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $j++;

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**I guess this is working,**

```
<?php

$product = '[{"product_id":"1","product_name":"Apple iMac","quantity":"32","unit":"23","unit_rate":"32"},{"product_id":"5","product_name":"Nokia E5","quantity":"543","unit":"543","unit_rate":"543"},{"product_id":"8","product_name":"Zinc Sulphate 500 ml","quantity":"5443","unit":"434","unit_rate":"5333"}]';

$products = json_decode($product, true);

print_r($products);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [product_name] => Apple iMac
            [quantity] => 32
            [unit] => 23
            [unit_rate] => 32
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [product_name] => Nokia E5
            [quantity] => 543
            [unit] => 543
            [unit_rate] => 543
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 8
            [product_name] => Zinc Sulphate 500 ml
            [quantity] => 5443
            [unit] => 434
            [unit_rate] => 5333
        )

)
```

**Demo:**
http://3v4l.org/5D3qe

**EDIT:**

```
foreach($res->result() as $row)
{
    $products = json_decode($row->product_name, true);

    foreach($products as $prod)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='hidden'  style='width:80%;'  value='".$prod['product_id']."' name='product_id[]'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='hidden'  style='width:80%;'  value='".$prod['product_name']."' name='product_name[]'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='width:40%;'>".$prod['product_name']."</td>";

        echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$prod['quantity']."' name='quantity[]'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$prod['unit']."' name='unit[]'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$prod['unit_rate']."' name='unit_rate[]'/></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' rownum='".$i."' class='remove_from_update_cart'><img src='images/close.png'/></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: As per your updated question, check the edits in the answer. You'll need another foreach loop.

Comment: Cool. Mind closing the answer as accepted for future use to others. :D

Comment: Okay you need a flag value as well. I didn't know that. You can accept your answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
json_decode($product, true);
```

To get as an array

Comment: What is  your PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

Try trimming:

```
foreach($res->result() as $row ){
                $product=$row->product_name;
                $products=json_decode(trim($product), 1);
                print_r($products);
}
```

Tried:

```
var_dump(json_decode('[{"product_id":"1","product_name":"Apple iMac","quantity":"32","unit":"23","unit_rate":"32"},{"product_id":"5","product_name":"Nokia E5","quantity":"543","unit":"543","unit_rate":"543"},{"product_id":"8","product_name":"Zinc Sulphate 500 ml","quantity":"5443","unit":"434","unit_rate":"5333"}]'));
```

**UPDATE:**

Not sure but, it can be [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64874) bug. I can see the white space between `Apple iMac`. One option left is to try updating PHP, this might be too much.

Try test cases from the bug link:

### Test script:

```
<?

function json_cmp($x, $y)
{
  print var_dump(json_decode($x) === $y);
}

// works
json_cmp("true", true);

// fails - is actually true
json_cmp("tRue", NULL);

// fails - is actually NULL
json_cmp("true ", true);

// works
json_cmp("[true ] ", array(true));

// works, even though the non-array version fails
json_cmp("[tRue]", NULL);

?>
```

### Expected result:

true * 5

### Actual result:

bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)

Comment: I manually tried decoding the string you mentioned in your question, that is working. So just a guess.

Comment: and try `var_dump` instead, print_r is specific to arrays.

Comment: Sorry I tried your manual code but It again display json string instead of array or object..

Comment: strange, confirm if extension is enabled in `phpinfo();`, just run this code in php tag. and look for `json`. are you on ubuntu ?